# How to save <script> as text in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

If I Enter "< script  >" tag in comment feild in my aspx page,  the design and layout of the page is distorted. I have written below line of code

in cs file

```
Result.CommentBody = Server.HtmlEncode(txtCommentBody.Text);
```

is aspx file

```
<asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("CommentBody").ToString()) %>' />
```

It does not work... Is there any alternate method to save and retrieve  as a text...   Please help me !!!

Comment: Do you want to keep other html markup, like bold-tags? If so, you need to write code to remove those script tags and their content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Literal` instead and set `Mode="Encode"`:

```
<asp:Literal ID="lblComment" Mode="Encode" runat="server"
     Text='<%# GetMethod(Eval("CommentBody").ToString())%>' />
```

Only reason you'd want a `Label` over a `Literal` is if you're **applying styles** to your text.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

in your aspx page

```
<asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
Text='<%# GetMethod(Eval("CommentBody").ToString())%>' />
```

in your codebehind

```
public string GetMethod(string CommentBody)
{


return Server.HtmlEncode(CommentBody);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're decoding instead of *encoding*. In order to show a script tag (actually any tag) you need to html encode special characters.

Call `Server.HtmlEncode` instead of `Server.HtmlDecode`, or if you store it encoded in your database (or who knows where), don't encode it again.